# Typescript: how to REQUIRE a property if a type is supplied and FORBID that property if the type is not supplied?

Tags: typescript

I am returning data from an express REST api. I want to make my API communication tight with the client. To do this, I'm trying to create a function `apiJsonResponse` through which all my returned data will be funneled on the server. Here's an example of what I have so far:

```
// Example route 1
router.get('/authorized', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  return apiJsonResponse<{ foo: string }>(res, 200, {
    message: 'Success',
    data: { foo: 'bar' }
  });
});

// Example route 2
router.get('/unauthorized', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  return apiJsonResponse(res, 401, {
    message: 'User is not authorized',
    isMessageDisplayable: true
  });
});

// Type-explicit wrapper around `res.status().json()`
function apiJsonResponse<T = undefined>(res: Response, status: number, body: TBody<T>): Response {
  return res.status(status).json(body);
}

// My attempt to type for a 'data-case' and a 'no-data-case'
type TBody<T> = T extends undefined ? IBody : IDataBody<T>;

interface IBody {
  message: string; // Event descriptor
  isMessageDisplayable?: boolean; // Flag whether or not to show user message
}

interface IDataBody<T> extends IBody {
  data: T; // Data payload if query is successful
}
```

So, basically, I am trying to enable two types of data response.

CASE 1: No data payload. This is chiefly for 4xx/5xx events where I return a message and indicate whether it's displayable to the end user.

CASE 2. Data payload. Chiefly for 2xx events where there is a data payload returned.

Now, what I want is for my function `apiJsonResponse` to *require* the body parameter to include a data property of type T iff this function is called with that type: `apiJsonResponse<T>(url,{data: x, ... })` where x satisfies `T`. This way, my client can fetch from such a route and expect the body to contain a data property of that same type (thereby my server and client can be made to communicate with the same interface).

Conversely, if my function is called without any type declared then inclusion of a data property within the body parameter will be *prohibited* by typescript.

I expected my code above to do the trick, but it does not. For example, the following call to the apiJsonResponse function has no type supplied, includes a `data` parameter in the body, but does NOT raise a typescript error:

```
apiJsonResponse(res, 200, {
    message: 'Success sending basic test',
    data: { test: 'hello-world' },
    isMessageDisplayable: true
  });
```

Evidently, my understanding of the typescript conditional has been found wanting. I reasoned that by not supplying a type the function would adopt the default `undefined` value (see: `<T = undefined>` above), and that the conditional statement `T extends undefined ? IBody : IDataBody<T>` would thereby return `IBody` when no type is supplied. However, this is not the case; rather, the above code seems to always return IDataBody whether or not a type is supplied.

Clarity and/or solutions at to what is going on here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out the problem and a solution. The original code was close (it's not a problem with conditionals), but Typescript wants to infer the type T when you supply parameters with concrete values to the apiJsonResponse function and then, based on that inference, it will select the latter interface (`IDataBody<T>`) in the conditional.

To prevent type inference, you can base your type logic on a second type variable that extends the first. The following modifications gave me the exact behavior I was looking for:

```
export function apiJsonResponse<T = undefined, U extends T = T>(
  res: Response,
  status: number,
  body: TBody<U>
): Response {
  return res.status(status).json(body);
}
```